# How can I stop users removing cells in the header row in handsontable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, handsontable

I want to make it so that the header row is not editable. I have managed to make it read only which means when they left click the cell they cannot edit it. However, they can right click the cell and choose remove row or column.

One way to do this is perhaps, intercept the bit where they remove the row or column and then check if that cell is readOnly or not. But how can I do this with Handsontables?

Answer (score 0):

You can set `contextMenu: false`in the options, or you can configure the context menu to not display "Remove Column" and "Remove Row":

http://handsontable.com/demo/contextmenu.html

Comment: That will disable the option completely. I want to only make the header row non-editable. Not everything else.

Comment: @JohnathanAu Can you add your code to the question?

Answer (score 0):

You should use [colHeaders](https://github.com/handsontable/handsontable/wiki/Options#column-options) so the row will not be right-clickable and you can define it, as an array or using a function.